# Chrome is not running javascript garbage collector

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, garbage-collection, v8

we have a single page application built with javascript, angular, etc.
 noticed that in Chrome (only) the memory usage is rising until the tab crash with the "Aw snap" message.

seems like Chrome is not running the garbage collector when it should.

after some research with old Chrome versions i've found that in version 61 everything works very good and the memory usage is very minimal, but in v62 and onward (including canary v66) the GC is not collecting, resulting in memory usage up to few giga. until it crash.

once i open the devtools the GC is collecting as it should and memory usage is normal again.

any idea what is happening?

Comment: Are you using some third party libs? For instance highcharts? I had a memory problem with highcharts, where I periodically reinitialized my charts without explicitly destroying them. I think somehow references where kept alive on this. I fixed it in my case by manually destroying the highcharts instance and then reassign a new instance to the variable.

Comment: 1) in FF (and other browsers) everything works pristine.
2) when opening devtools of chrome everything works good as well.
so it seems to be not a problem with our app.

Comment: Then maybe some kind of loop reserving memory in very short distances. I think of this, because with opened devtools, the execution of your code is slightly slower and this migh be enough for the GC to do his job. And with "normal" execution speed it can't. Its just a wild guess, tho.

Comment: ok @scipper, thanks for the help, at this moment i'll try everything. but... how come the same code tuns fine in v61 but bad in v62?

Comment: well, features might change in there implementation. currently I have trouble running protractor tests with v64, which ran fine with v63 :/

Answer (score 0):

Chrome developer here. It's hard to guess what might be going on. Please file a bug at [crbug.com/new](http://crbug.com/new), include repro instructions, and post the bug number here.